# Could not determine type for entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have two classes:

```
public ClassAEntity extends ClassA {

   private Long id;

   @Override
   public void doSomething() {
     // do something
   }

}

public abstract ClassA {

   public abstract void doSomething();

}
```

And the JPA ORM file containing:

```
<entity class="ClassAEntity" access="FIELD">
    <attributes>
        <id name="id">
            <column name="seqid" />
            <generated-value strategy="IDENTITY" />
        </id>
    </attributes>
</entity>
```

Yet during initialization I get the following error:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type
>   for: com.example.ClassA, at table: ClassAEntity, for columns:
>   [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(classA)]

But there is no such column! What's wrong with all this? Can't I just have abstract class for my entity?

**Finally solved:**
Just remember that using JPA mappings (ORM xmls) will make persistence try to map all fields of the Entity by default whereas hibernate mappings do not do this. So check for each field at class level - there might be an unmapped reference to the abstract class as in my case.

Comment: I think that you must declare your ClassA as an entity.

Answer (score 0):

My friend please apply, all proper annotation at entity level and field level and Mapping of hibernate like one to one, many to one. then rerun it and get back with your updates

```
you can refer this site as well
http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/one-to-many-jpa-hibernate-config-jpa-entity-config.html
```

Answer (score 0):

You can

- declare ClassA with `Entity`
  or
- declare ClassA as `MappedSuperClass` : this is the way i recommand, becauce it's seems ClassA does not embed ID.

Comment: Maybe default constructors ?

Comment: All entities do have default, package-level constructors.